# `heroku logs` command not showing any logs

Tags: heroku, logging, heroku-cli

On a Mac, in Terminal, when I type the command
`heroku logs -a APPNAME` (where `APPNAME` is the name of my app), I don't see any logs show up in terminal.

Comment: What is output of this command ?

Comment: @svikramjeet nothing - no message returned.

Comment: Getting the same thing. the command hangs for about 5 seconds then returns with no output. Also tried `heroku logs -t -a APPNAME`. I am on windows. Very frustrating.

Comment: Josiah I posted this such a long time ago that I don't remember, but I think I might have realized I actually had the wrong appname? I was using an app name for a dummy app that I had made that was named very similarly to the real app... Might be completely off, but throwing out a vague memory